Chabad's position on learning the Alshich Hakodesh
I haven't seen the Alshich Hakodesh quoted much, if at all, by Chabad sources. That could simply be my bad memory, or it didn't occur within my scope of learning.
Given that the Alshich was a contemporary of the Arizal, rather than a student, I wonder if that means that Chabad view his teachings as a different branch of teachings, or something. I am just speculating.
Therefore I would like to ask if

Chabad quote the Alshich much?
there is a formal position by Chabad on the Alshich and his teachings?


https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9A

He's quoted here - https://www.sefaria.org/Likkutei_Torah%2C_Metzora.11?vhe=Kehot_Publication_Society&lang=bi by the Baal HaTanya

Also quoted multiple times on the Chabad website here - https://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/11751/jewish/Alshich-R-Moshe.htm

There's 100+ hits on chabadlibrary.org
